# stringName.upper() in python only upcases letter C

Tags: python, uppercase

Allo,
I have been trying to make a stopwatch / countdown timer in python, and when I type in my raw_input to choose what type of timer (stopwatch or countdown), it converts the C (for countdown) to upcase when I put it in, but when I put in S (for stopwatch), it does not upcase it. I have tried putting in a few different letters but those dont work either. Here is my code:

```
typeOfTimer = raw_input("What type of timer do you want? enter c for countdown and s for stopwatch. ")
typeOfTimer.upper()

print typeOfTimer

if typeOfTimer == "C":
    countdown()
elif typeOfTimer == "S":
    stopwatch()
else:
    print "Invalid type"
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.upper()` does not modify the variable. Instead, assign it with your `raw_input()`:

```
typeOfTimer = raw_input("What type of timer do you want? enter c for countdown and s for stopwatch. ").upper()
```

Here is your updated code:

```
typeOfTimer = raw_input("What type of timer do you want? enter c for countdown and s for stopwatch. ").upper()

print typeOfTimer

if typeOfTimer == "C":
    countdown()
elif typeOfTimer == "S":
    stopwatch()
else:
    print "Invalid type"
```

---

As you can see, just calling `.upper()` does not change the variable unless assigned.

```
>>> x = 'c'
>>> x.upper()
'C'
>>> x
'c'
>>> x = x.upper()
>>> x
'C'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.upper()` creates a new string from the old. It doesn't mutate the string you call the method with. Try this instead:

```
typeOfTimer = typeOfTimer.upper()
```